# Google maps MarkerImage with local url won't display in Safari mobile iOS 6

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mobile-safari

I have a Google map embedded in my web page, and I want to create a marker using a custom image.  Here is the code to add the marker.  'map' is a variable representing the Google map object.

```
function addMarker(location) {
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("tree.gif", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(16, 24));
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
};
```

This works fine in IE 8, Chrome 25, Firefox 19 and Safari 5 (desktop) - the marker is created and the tree.gif image is displayed.  However, this does not work in Safari mobile on iOS 6 (iPad and iPhone).

This DOES work on Safari mobile if:

1. ...I remove the custom icon - the default Google maps marker icon (red pushpin) appears
2. ...I use a remote url to some other image file (eg/ http://somedomain.com/images/someimage.gif)

I've been all over SOF and Google groups with no luck.  Any ideas?

ADDED 3/12/13: [This site](http://bsatreerecycle.herokuapp.com) is live and exhibits this behavior (at last check).  Start with the "Mark" page to post a marker at your GPS location, then check the "Map" page to see if your marker shows up. Source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/mattskone/bsatreerecycle) - problem is in scripts/map.js file.

ADDED 3/15/13: Narrowed it down.  My page also uses HTML5 server-sent events.  The above behavior occurs only when the EventSource connection is open.  However, if I comment out this line, the markers appear as expected (link to code in previous para):

```
var source = new EventSource('../pickups');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the solution, but I figured out why this is happening.  As described in [this post](http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/21/ajax-web-apps-in-ios-6-are-sort-of-broken/), among other places, Safari in iOS 6 appears to allow only one http connection at a time per host.

As soon as I create a new EventSource as shown in the code above, Safari keeps only that new connection (to '/pickups') open and ignores the original connection (to '/map').  No other resources on the original connection, including my tree GIF, will be fetched after that point.  That explains why the default Google maps marker (fetched from google.com) and images from other hosts work fine.

Until I find a better solution, I'll use polling for Safari iOS 6 clients instead of EventSource.